# I can't do 2 times append at one struct in Go

Tags: json, go, struct, model

I have nested struct/model that will used for query. I want assign value from request to my struct but there are value that need some condition before assign it. But it's didn't work like I want.

Input:

```
{
    "item_name": "asd",
    "item_type": "A",
    "sub_items": [
        {
            "sub_id": 1,
            "sub_name": "qwe"
        },
        {
            "sub_id": 2,
            "sub_name": "zxc"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have: `model.go`

```
type Inventory struct {
  ID       int       `json:"id" db:""`
  ItemName string    `json:"item_name" db:""`
  ItemType string    `json:"item_type" db:""`   //type: "A", "B", "C"
  SubItems []SubItem `json:"sub_items" db:""`
}

type SubItem {
  SubID   int `json:"sub_id" db:""`
  SubName string `json:"sub_name" db:""`
  SubType string `json:"sub_type" db:""`       //type: "D", "E", "F"
}
```

What I did:

```
// req = from_input
request := &model.Inventory{
        ItemName: req.ItemName,
        ItemType: req.ItemType,
}

for key, pieces := range req.SubItems {
    request.SubItems = append(request.SubItems, model.SubItems{
            SubName:   pieces.SubName,
    })

    if req.ItemType == "A" {
        request.SubItems = append(request.SubItems, model.SubItems{
            SubType:   "D",
        })
    }
}

fmt.Println(request.SubItems[0].SubType)

// result = ""
```

I don't have any idea why the result is empty, my `req.ItemType` is `"A"`.

Comment: Where is `req` defined? It looks like `req.SubItems` is probably empty.

Comment: You add a subitem with a name, but not subtype. Then you conditionally add another subitem with a subtype but no name. Printing the first one will clearly have an empty subtype.

Comment: my ```req``` not empty

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, pieces := range req.SubItems {
    request.SubItems = append(request.SubItems, model.SubItems{ // adds a subitem with a name but no type
            SubName:   pieces.SubName,
    })

    if req.ItemType == "A" {
        request.SubItems = append(request.SubItems, model.SubItems{ // adds another subitem with a type but no name
            SubType:   "D",
        })
    }
}
```

I'm guessing what you wanted was to add only 1 `SubItem` and conditionally set the `SubType` of that one item.

Instead acces the last element of the slice and modify it

```
for key, pieces := range req.SubItems {
    request.SubItems = append(request.SubItems, model.SubItems{
            SubName:   pieces.SubName,
    })

    if req.ItemType == "A" {
        request.SubItems[request.SubItems.length - 1].SubType = "D"
    }
}
```

Comment: how if i need to add many ```SubItem``` ?

Comment: That's what the loop does already.... ? For every subitem in `req.SubItem` you add one subitem to `request.SubItem`.